# Show only the meetings where the user is the organizer with EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

is there a way to search all users calendar (the are all in a distribution group) and show only the meetings, where they are the oranizers?

I am using impersonation.

With the following code I can get the organizer of a Meeting:

```
        //Instantiate the ExchangeService class+ Exchange Certificate Validation + Imparsonate
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("user@domain", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

        //Distinguish Distribution Group
        string distributiongroup = "distributiongroup@domain";

        // Initialize values for the start and end time.
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(0);
        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

        //Extend the distribution group
        ExpandGroupResults distGroupMembers = service.ExpandGroup(distributiongroup);
        foreach (EmailAddress address in distGroupMembers.Members)
        {
            //Impersonate each distribution group member
            service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, address.Address);

            // Execute the search in the calendar folder and return the view
            CalendarView caledarView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);
            caledarView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> apt = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, caledarView);

            foreach (Item item in apt.Items)
            {
                ServiceResponseCollection<GetItemResponse> myColl = service.BindToItems(new[] { new ItemId(item.Id.UniqueId) }, caledarView.PropertySet);
                foreach (GetItemResponse temp in myColl)
                {
                    Appointment app = (Appointment)temp.Item;

                    string organizator = app.Organizer.Address;

                    Console.WriteLine(address + "\n" + app.Subject + " " + organizator);
                }
            }
```

My goal is to get only the meetings for every user, where he is the organizer.

Can you help me on this one?

Kind Regards
Xristos

Comment: What's your problem/question regarding this matter ?

Comment: I want to list only the appointments wich the user is an organizer.

Comment: You could build a list containing Appointment objects and then use LINQ query to get only the appointment you want even if I admit it's not really a solution.

Comment: I have managed to solve my Problem with organizator==address.Address.

Comment: @user3197311 For clarity, please write your own answer. You can mark it as the correct answer after 2 days IIRC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (organizator == address.Address)
```

{
"do something"
}